# Oledb Issues while reading data from an Excel file in a website hosted on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis, oledb

I have a website which will use OleDB.12.0 to read data from an Excel worksheet upon upload. It works fine on my local PC. But when hosted in my production server I get the following error.

> microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 is not registered on the local machine

How can I correct this?

My production server configuration:

- MS Office 2007.
- IIS 7
- VS 2010
- Windows 2008 R2
- SQL Server2008

Answer (score 1):

Does your production server have Access installed?

In any event, try installing/reinstalling [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) to the production server.

**Update**

Another point: is your production server running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? Choose the download appropriately.

**Update 2**

From [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64) it appears that using the 64-bit version will cause trouble on a 32-bit system, but the 32-bit version will work.

Comment: Hi Zev. thanks for the reply.i have MS 2010 Installed on my Production Server,which means Microsoft Access 2010 is already installed on my Production Server.Are you asking something different?Please Help.I am in Trouble.

Comment: Hi Zev,Also can you specify why we need to Install extra 3rd Party S/W,to fix this.Is there any way to hadle it without installing it.Thanks

Comment: Technically it's not 3rd party software, as it's all from Microsoft :) . The Access *database engine*, which actually reads tables and runs queries, is distinct from the Access *application*, which lets you create forms and reports. The engine itself is also probably installed, but this error means that the OLE DB driver for the Access engine is not installed/registered properly. Reinstalling the engine might reregister the engine properly with OLE DB.

Comment: hi Zev,can u also mention that if it has something do do with bits installation.I mean i have 32bit- MS OFFICE 2010 installed on my Production.Which is a 64 bit machine.Also,if idownload the above microsoft path,will it be compatible with 32 bit MS OFFICE 2010. Please show me some light on it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nks See the link I posted. I'm I afraid don't have any personal experience with the problem, as I am running on a 32-bit machine myself.